# How to exchange two class by value ,not reference?

Tags: vb.net

There are two classes in `ArrayList`.I want to exchange all their values but not their reference.For example , arraylist1(1) refers to the same class after exchanging , with its value changed.

If I change them in this way

```
Dim someclass1 as new someclass
Dim someclass2 as new someclass
arraylist1(1) = someclass1
arraylist1(2) = someclass2
temp = arraylist1(1)
arraylist1(1) = arraylist1(2)
arraylist1(2) = temp
```

It only exchange the reference.arraylist1(1) just refers to someclass2 but actually I want it refers to someclass1 with someclass2's value.
Now I just exchange their important properities one by one.

Comment: You have to write code to swap all of the fields and properties yourself. The framework won't do this for you. And who uses ArrayList in 2018 anyway? It's been a legacy type since VS2005, only there for backwards compatibility.

Comment: *"There are two classes in `ArrayList`"*. Objects, not classes. *"For example , arraylist1(1) refers to the same class after exchanging"*. Same object, not same class. Consider the real world. You and I are people. `Person` is the class and you and I are objects, i.e. instances of that class.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn So now List takes place of it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy properties yourself, one by one. You can make it a bit easier by adding two methods to your class:

```
Public Class SampleClass
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Name As String

    Public Function Clone() As SampleClass
        Return New SampleClass With
        {
            .Id = Me.Id,
            .Name = Me.Name
        }
    End Function

    Public Sub Init(input As SampleClass)
        With Me
            .Id = input.Id
            .Name = input.Name
        End With
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub SwapValues(value1 As SampleClass, value2 As SampleClass)
        Dim temp = value1.Clone()
        value1.Init(value2)
        value2.Init(temp)
    End Sub
End Class
```

And then when trying to swap values:

```
SampleClass.SwapValues(list(0), list(1))
```